# Binding Object Properties to Specific Telerik RadGridView Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, telerik

I am defining the data source of a Telerik RadGridView control in its NeedDataSource event. The data source in question is an IEnumerable collection of objects.

Say, for example, the column order in the RadGridView is `Title | Description | Date`. If I have the following objects in my collection...

```
class Obj{

  public DateTime Date {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Description {get;set;}

}
```

How do I ensure when using `RadGridView1.DataSource();`that the object property values are assigned to the RadGridView columns in the correct order?

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you?  If not, let me know how I can improve it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question.  Are you using `Auto generate columns at runtime`?  If not: the column order is defined by you declaratively, like this:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ObjId">
                 <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:M/dd/yyyy}">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Title" HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Description" HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid1>
```

Notice that the `DataField` is telling the RadGrid which object property to use.  If I've completely missed your question, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are auto generating the columns and would like to reorder them programatically, you can use the SwapColumns method discussed [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-reordering-columns.html).  The columns should be added automatically in alphabetical order, so just calling the below should work.

```
grid.MasterTableView.SwapColumns("Date","Title");
```

It worked for me to put this in the DataBound event handler.